# Blog style pages in Django with different content types. Best model structure

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm relatively new to Django development. I'm building a website where there is a section with tutorials. Lets say for my question a tutorial for Linked List. Since all the tutorials will be basically the same outline, it looks like that templates will do a good job here. What I want to achieve is that I can create new pages (tutorial entries ) in the admin panel, with text fields and so on (kind of like a blog without the relevance of the dates rather then the tutorials content). The challenge for me is, that there is a different amount of different types of data in one tutorial entries. For example one might have the structure:

- text
- code
- text
- image
- text
- code

and another one:

- text
- image
- code

And if I made a new entry it should get generated with a template as it is done usually in Django. I thought about three ways to meet this dynamic behavior but I see difficulties in each and want to know what the best practice would be.

So the structure would be similar to a Blog:

```
class TutorialPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    text_content = models.TextField()
    code_block = models.TextField()
    #....
```

The problem here is that I don't know how to achieve thy dynamic behavior since I could need more text fields or code blocks in a different order.

I was also thinking of having only one text field and treating it as a markdown field. So I would get a markdown package such as Django MarkdownX, and would compile the contend of  text_content. The problem here is, that I have much less freedom in how the design of the e.g. code block can look like (syntax highlighting, background and so on).

My last idea was that I again only have one text_content field as entry option but put plain text, code, images etc in own tags (similar to the three accents used here at stackoverflow) and process/parse these afterwards to present them in the proper order on request.

I'm looking forward to get some input.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do a model for each content type, like this.

```
class TextContent(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField()
    post = models.ForeignKey(TutorialPost, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This way you can create multiple "content blocks" of the same time on a single post.

And for the order, you can create a custom `OrderField`, here is a example.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

class OrderField(models.PositiveIntegerField):
    def __init__(self, for_fields=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.for_fields = for_fields
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def pre_save(self, model_instance, add):
        if getattr(model_instance, self.attname) is None:
            # No current value
            try:
                qs = self.model.objects.all()
                if self.for_fields:
                    # Filter by objects with the same field values
                    # for the fields in 'for_fields'
                    query = {field: getattr(model_instance, field)\
                        for field in self.for_fields}
                    qs = qs.filter(**query)
                # Get the order of the last item
                last_item = qs.latest(self.attname)
                value = last_item.order + 1
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                value = 0
            setattr(model_instance, self.attname, value)
            return value
        else:
            return super().pre_save(model_instance, add)
```

Comment: Thx, for your answer I'll try that.